# Google Play Console automatic add a permission

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

I have submit new version of my app but this time google says:

```
New permissions added   
 Users who use the APK with version 18 code may need to accept the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission, which may make it impossible to upgrade to this version of the app.
```

But i never used this permission in my APK

[image]

I use only this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have the same problem. No new permissions have been added. Where it came from I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Google API https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: Consider future visitors; it would be best to alter the link to the specific release that addressed the bug. In this case, that appears to be https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_28_2018_-_verison_1201 (yes, the hyperlink has a typo on their end!)
Even better, copy the substance of the remark from the API release document here.